# Why can I not find my index.html in WinSCP and replace it to make my Apache2 VPS server website hosting work?

Tags: html, apache, apache2, vps

In my rented **VPS** server and am using **Apache2**. I created an index.html file in the folder /var/www/html/. This .html file is correctly displayed when opening my new webpage.
However, I want to transfer my project from VS Code to my folder, thus replace the original index.html file with my big index.html file that I made in VS code.

My issues are the following:

- I can only open and edit the index.html file by using sudo vim
  /var/www/html/index.html This file will then be displayed on my
  website.
- If I insert an index.html file from WinSCP or use vim index.html in
  /var/www/html/ I edit a different html file that is not being
  displayed on my website.
- I cant see the index.html file from sudo vim /var/www/html/index.html
  in WinSCP.

--> Also this happens when adding a html file with winSCP: sudo chmod 644 /var/www/html/index.html
chmod: cannot access '/var/www/html/index.html': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

My files over WinSCP were in the relative path, but for Apache they need to be in the real path. So what I did to fix this was:

```
mv ~/var/www/html/* /var/www/html/
```

This command moves the stuff from the relative path to the real path of `/var/www/html/`.